# Do we need to average all predictions from neural network or other learners?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

When neural network is ran multiple times to get N predictions, do we need to average all of them, including runs with bad validation scores or early stopping triggered too soon?

One theoretical reason to exclude is bad weight initialization, therefore bad runs are not from the same distribution. Is this good enough reason to exclude bad runs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can't say. What works best will depend on your specific use case and network.

Note that distinguishing "good" from "bad" predictions is itself a statistical classification task. Which you can again get wrong. You might treat a bad prediction as a "good" one and include it in your averaging, although you shouldn't have, or vice versa. This added uncertainty is a strong argument for including every prediction without trying to evaluate which ones will be better or worse.

That equal weights in combining forecasts often works better than estimating "optimal" weights (and possibly setting some weights to zero) has been called the ["forecast combination puzzle"](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%22forecast+combination+puzzle%22&t=ffsb&ia=web) and has been the focus of some research.